# How handle() method of Laravel middleware is called using 'Clousre $next' in another Middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

Here is a handle() method from Laravel's *ValidatePostSize*:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $max = $this->getPostMaxSize();

    if ($max > 0 && $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $max) {
        throw new PostTooLargeException;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now, this method is called using *$next($request)* for another Middleware. What my understanding is that *handle()* method get translated to *$next*. I want to know how this happens under the hood.

Comment: look up the code ?

Comment: It's the next Middleware closure in the stack.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson look the description of question. I know its closure as it has hinted in method. What I want to know is how handle() method is translated to closure $next.

Comment: @MayankKumar my answer may get you know how Closure works.

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo I am not asking how closure works. Actully its a larvale question and $next is mapped to handle() method of middleware. I want to know how this mapping is working

Comment: If you understand how Closure works, you will understand why it is used. The purpose of `$next` inside `handle` is to do particular things that should not be done by the `handle` itself. In `ValidatePostSize` case, `next` is responsible for executing conditional validation. [Validation - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) (read section "Complex Conditional Validation").

Comment: Once again, actually whats happening here is that there are many middleware in laravel and all of them have handle(request $request, closure $next) method. Now, $next in each of them is mapped to handle() of other. i.e. when $next run, it runs handle() method of another middleware.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> To pass the request deeper into the application (allowing the middleware to "pass"), simply call the $next callback with the $request.
> **https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#defining-middleware**

When Laravel is handling a request it runs all the applicable middleware in the stack. Middleware can be set to run before and/or after the route/controller method.

To be able to do this Laravel uses `Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline`. Essentially, it uses `array_reduce` to iterate over the middleware stack which then returns a `Closure` to execute that middleware. The beauty to this comes from using `array_reverse` allowing the next middleware execution to be passed to the previous one.

---

To elaborate a little bit more:

When the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel@handle` is called it builds up the response with `sendRequestThroughRouter` which has the following in it:

```
return (new Pipeline($this->app))
            ->send($request)
            ->through($this->app->shouldSkipMiddleware() ? [] : $this->middleware)
            ->then($this->dispatchToRouter());
```

`Pipeline` is `Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline` which extends `Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline`.

The `then()` method above is essentially:

```
->then(function ($request) {
    $this->app->instance('request', $request);

    return $this->router->dispatch($request);
})
```

Then means that we're starting off with a closure that accepts the end results (remember at this point that closure won't have been called).

Then, in the `then()` method, the `array_reduce` and `array_reverse` section as mentioned above happens.

---

Here is a simplified example of what actually happens in the `then()` method (this assumes you know how `array_reduce` works):

```
function then(Closure $destination)
{
    $pipeline = array_reduce(

        array_reverse($this->middlewares),

        //Remember $nextClosure is going to be the closure returned 
        //from the previous iteration

        function ($nextClosure, $middlewareClass) {

            //This is the $next closure you see in your middleware
            return function ($request) use ($nextClosure, $middlewareClass) {

                //Resolve the middleware
                $middleware = app($middlewareClass);

                //Call the middleware
                return $middleware->{$this->method}($request, $nextClosure);
            };
        },

        //The finial closure that will be called that resolves the destination

        function ($request) use ($destination) {
            return $destination($request);
        }
    );

    return $pipeline($this->request);
}
```

Say we have 3 middlewares:

```
[
    One::class,
    Two::class,
    Three::class,
];
```

The `$pipeline` variable above would basically be:

```
function ($request) {

    return app(One::class)->handle($request, function ($request) {

        return app(Two::class)->handle($request, function ($request) {

            return app(Three::class)->handle($request, function ($request) {

                return $destination($request);

            });
        };);
    };);
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please? I think all the magic is happening in Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php. A simple example will be great.

Comment: @MayankKumar I've added a bit more.

Comment: If I want to implement this without using pipeline, how should I approach?

Comment: @MayankKumar I don't understand your question. Do you mean in a none laravel project?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @RossWilson Your explanation is great in the context of laravel. I found this feature pretty powerful and would like to generalize it. How could I implement it in simplest form(Without pipeline and laravel)?

Comment: @MayankKumar That does go out of the scope of this question and it would completely depend on how you handle requests and responses to your app, how you would assign middleware to different routes/requests etc. That being said, on a very basic level, you would just create an array of classes/function that you want to call, make sure each one receives a closure and basically use the **simplified example** above.

Comment: @RossWilson Thanks a lot. Great explanation!!

Answer (score 2):

Next is a Closure, a variable of anonymous function. In your code, you have `return $next($request);`. $next is a Closure, based on your second method parameter. That means the return value of your method is something that the anonymous function return.

For example:

```
// this is the Closure.
$next = function ($parameter) {
    return $parameter . ' This message is modified by $next';
};

public function handle($message, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($message);
}

// test the output
$message = 'Hello World!';
echo handle($message, $next); // output will be 'Hello World! This message is modified by $next'
```